# Add js in head in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, xml

All js script are loaded in footer in **magento 1.9**. I want them in head.
Can Anyone let how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Who told you that the **JS** files are loaded in **footer** ? the JS files are declared and loaded from and in `head`.

Here is the native way how to include a JS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script_name.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: In default its in head. but there is an script or something that pull the js in footer

Comment: So if I decide to remove the footer from my website, there will be no JS that will be loaded ?

Comment: Do you use an extension for page-speed?
We have an extension from amasty, that provides the function to move the javascript to the footer. Its not the default behavior of magento1 (but it can be positive regarding page-speed)

Answer (score 0):

To add js in the head you can edit layout xml files where you want your scripts in the head.

Example in \app\design\frontend[your-theme]\default\layout\page.xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>script.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>script2.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>script3.js</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This are just some examples. Hope this helps.

**Edit:** I think you have a modified version of Magento 1.9 because in the default version all js are in the head.